# Is there a way i can embed virtual reality scenes using arcore_flutter_plugin

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore, virtual-reality

Just wanted to inquire is there any way i can embed VIRTUAL REALITY using [arcore_flutter_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/arcore_flutter_plugin), One can do this using [arkit_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/arkit_plugin) checkout this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmiRYar996w&t=1147s , but problem is that arkit is compatible with only. Is there any similar way i can do this in arcore_flutter_plugin?
A simple answer that describes how to do that, perhaps with code will suffice